# What is the most suitable name for Local Features research topic?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection

During my current research I have been reading about a computer vision topic which no one seems to agree on what to call it: **"Local Features"**
In my opinion, all the names make some sense, they are different ways of describing the topic.

I have seen the all of following descriptions that seem to refer to the same thing:

- Natural Features
- Local Invariant Features (Sometimes more specific: Scale/Rotation Invariant Features)
- Feature Points
- Interest Points
- Keypoints
- And other variants from above.

Which one is more appropriate to name this research topic or are there significant differences between them?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better placed on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I though about it, maybe putting it at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com, but all these stackexchange sites result in fragmenting the community, in my opinion, and I wanted to see what the SO community could answer. Question topics sometimes are related to several top level categories like programming, computer science, signal processing, but this would be another discussion.

Comment: I think it is indifferent unless you use SIFT, which uses the word "keypoints". The others are more or less the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being invariant is a specific quality it means that given a change to the invariant property (scale/rotation/etc), the description remains constant. As for the difference between feature points/interest points/keypoints I think that's fairly subjective, although I'd probably argue that feature or keypoint were probably the most common.

Answer (score 0):

I worked a lot with SIFT, and the word that came the most often was definitely keypoint, so in my opinion it is the more appropriate, since, after all, finding keypoints is just a part of a bigger picture.